# How to remove duplicate records being returned?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have 3 tables: users, posts, and likes. I want to do a lambda expression to return an array that holds username, postText, and liked (true or false)

```
 var myList = _context.Posts.Join(_context.Users,
            post => post.UserID_FK,
            user => user.ID,
            (post, user) => new { Post = post, User = user })
            .Join(
            _context.Likes,
            u => u.User.ID,
            likes => likes.UserID,
            (u, likes) => new PostDTO
            {
                ID = u.Post.ID,
                username = u.Patient.UserName,
                Text = u.Post.Text,
                Likes = u.Post.Likes,
                liked = (likes.PostID == u.Post.ID && likes.UserID == userModel.ID)}
          .OrderByDescending(d => d.Date);

        return myList;
```

My problem is with my code I am getting everything I want, but i am getting repeated records. I am trying to understand why I am getting duplicate records? I have searched lambda expressions and I can not figure out where my issue is.

I thank you guys in advance!

Comment: please enter sample data and desired output

Comment: Post your model. Probably you do not need joins here.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because like with an SQL query joining tables you are building a Cartesian for all combinations. As a simple example of a Post with 2 Likes where we run an SQL statement with an inner join:

```
SELECT p.PostId, l.LikeId FROM Posts p INNER JOIN Likes l ON p.PostId == l.PostId WHERE p.PostId = 1
```

we would get back:

```
PostId     LikeId
  1            1
  1            2
```

Obviously, returning more data from Post and Like to populate a meaningful view, but the raw data will look to have a lot of duplication. This compounds with the more 1-to-many relationships, so you need to manually interpret the data to resolve that you are getting back one post with two Likes.

When you utilize navigation properties correctly to map the relationships between your entities, EF will do the heavy lifting to turn these Cartesian combinations back into a meaningful model structure.

For example, take the following model structure:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    // ... Other Post-related data fields.

    public virtual User Patient { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; } = new List<Like>();
}

public class Like
{
    public int LikeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; } 
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

EF can likely work out all of these relationships automatically via convention, but I recommend being familiar with explicit configuration because there is always a time when convention fails in a particular situation where you want or need to use a different naming convention. There are four options for resolving relationships in EF: Convention, Attributes, `EntityTypeConfiguration`, and using `OnModelCreating`'s modelBuilder. The below example outlines `EntityTypeConfiguration` via EF6. EF Code uses an interface called IEntityTypeConfiguration which works in a similar way but you implement a method for the configuration rather than call base-class methods in a constructor. Attributes and Convention are generally the least amount of work, but I typically run into situations they don't map. (They do seem to be more reliable with EF Core) Configuring via modelBuilder is an option for smaller applications but  it gets cluttered very quicky.

```
public class PostConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
{
    public PostConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Posts");
        HasKey(x => x.PostId)
            .Property(x => x.PostId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    
        HasRequired(x => x.Patient)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("PatientUserId"));
 
        HasMany(x => x.Likes)
            .WithRequired(x => x.Post)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("PostId"));
    }
}

public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Users");
        HasKey(x => x.UserId)
            .Property(x => x.UserId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}

public class LikeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Like>
{
    public LikeConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Likes");
        HasKey(x => x.LikeId)
            .Property(x => x.LikeId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    
        HasRequired(x => x.User)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("UserId"));
    }
}

// In your DbContext
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
}
```

Now when you want to query your data, EF will manage the FK relationships and resolving any Joins and resulting Cartesian products. The question just becomes what data do you want out of the domain model?

```
var viewData = _context.Posts
    .Select(p => new PostDTO
    {
        ID = p.PostID,
        UserName = p.Patient.UserName,
        Text = p.Text,
        Likes = p.Likes
            .Select(l => new LikeDTO
            {
                ID = l.LikeId
                UserName = l.User.UserName
            }).ToList(),
        Liked = p.Likes.Any(l => l.User.UserId == userModel.UserId)
    }).OrderByDescending(p => p.Date)
    .ToList();
```

This is a rough guess based on your original query where you want the posts, patient name, likes, and an indicator whether the current user liked the post or not. Note there are no explicit joins or even eager loading. (`Include`) EF will build the necessary statement with just the columns you need to populate your DTOs and the IDs necessary to relate the data.

You should also avoid mixing DTOs with Entities when returning data. In the above example I introduced a DTO for the Like as well as the Post since we want to return some detail about the Likes from our domain. We don't pass back references to Entities because when these get serialized, the serializer would try and touch each property which can cause lazy loading to get triggered and overall would return more information than our consumer needs or should potentially see.  With the relationships mapped and expressed through navigation properties EF will build a query with the required joins automatically and work through the returned data to populate what you expect to see.